# Cannot convert numpy dtypes to its native python types (int64 to int)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-dtype

Please check the below code, I want to convert the dtype int64 to its native python type int.

```
dfCredit = pd.DataFrame(credits_List)
dfCredit['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfCredit['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
sum_Credit_Bal = dfCredit.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()
avg_Credit_Bal = dfCredit.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).mean()
avg_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'] = sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'].astype(int)
print("--------------")
print("\nAverage amount Credited per month :\n\n ", avg_Credit_Bal)
print("--------------")
print(avg_Credit_Bal.dtypes)


js =  [{"Average amount Credited per month": avg_Credit_Bal.to_dict()}]
s3object = s3.Object("bank-statement-demo","BankOutput.json")
s3object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(js).encode('UTF-8'))))
```

I was trying to run my code in amazon lambda service and I got the following error

'TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable'. that why I need to convert it into its native python type

**Output**

```
Average amount Credited per month :

                Credit  No. of transactions
Month                                    
Jun-18   4644.500000                    4
Jul-18  11142.000000                    2
Aug-18  12148.750000                    4
Sep-18   2830.477143                    7
Oct-18   4664.250000                    4
Nov-18   8381.500000                    2
--------------
Credit                 float64
No. of transactions      int64
dtype: object
```

**Expected answer**

```
No. of transactions      int
```

Comment: why does this matter? You can change the dtype to `np.int32` using `astype('np.int32')`

Comment: @EdChum: I dont want it to be in `int32` or `int64` coz when i'm trying to convert it into json, I'm getting an error `TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I have edited my question. and I dont think int32 and int are same

Comment: try `avg_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'] = sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'].astype(object)`

Comment: how about `avg_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'] = sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'].astype(int).astype(object)`

Comment: @EdChum : that worked.

Comment: OK I'll post it as an answer later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that Amazon s3 is a bit sensitive to dtypes so in order for it to be compatible you can first cast to `int` and then to `object` so it's compatible:

```
avg_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'] = sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'].astype(int).astype(object)
```

If you look at the type of the elements it will output `object` indicating that it's a generic python object:

```
type(avg_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'][0])
```

will output `object`

Answer (score 0):

For converting numpy dtypes to native Python dtypes you have two options:

**Option 1:**

```
sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'].item()
```

**Option 2:**

```
np.asscalar(sum_Credit_Bal['No. of transactions'])
```